# Example of continuous cohomology vs cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

I am looking for an example of a locally compact group $G$ and a continuous $G$ module $M$, which also is locally compact, such that the continuous cochain cohomology differs from group cohomology (ignoring the topologies). In the literature, I find many results, giving criteria when they agree, but I could not find an example, in which they don't.

Comment: The stacks project claims [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DVG) that they are isomorphic when $G$ is discrete or profinite, but also asks for examples where they disagree.

Comment: Quote: "It is known that these maps [the canonical maps $H^i(G,M)\to H^i_{cont}(G,M)$] are isomorphisms when $G$ is an abstract group (i.e., $G$ has the discrete topology) or when $G$ is a profinite group (insert future reference here). If you know an example showing this map is not an isomorphism for a topological group $G$ and $M\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathrm{Mod}_G)$ please email stacks.project@gmail.com."

Comment: Also, as commented [there](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DVG#comment-7013), Remark 4.2.4 of _Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology_ seems like a potential example where the two disagree, but it depends on how you define $H^i(G,M)$ and $H^i_{cont}(G,M)$ (e.g. whether you take into account the topology of $G$ for $H^i(G,M)$ or not)

Comment: @Emily: I do take the topology of $G$ into account, so this is not a counterexample.

Comment: The Stacks project page with comments indicates that there is even a question to answer of what you mean by continuous group cohomology. Could you spell out a little more what definition you're using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the circle $G=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and its trivial representation on $M=\mathbb{R}$.
Since $G$ is abelian, $H^1(G,M)\cong \text{Hom}(G,M)$ and $H^1_c(G,M)\cong \text{Hom}_c(G,M)$ (these are the continuous versions).
Clearly, $\text{Hom}_c(G,M)=0$.
However, as abstract groups $\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, thus $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, thus $\text{Hom}(G,M)\cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R})$, which is huge, as both arguments are high dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Free pro-p group of rank at least $2$ is an example of such behaviour.

In the article "On discrete homology of a free pro-p-group", S. O. Ivanov, R. Mikhailov [publication](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/abs/on-discrete-homology-of-a-free-propgroup/4C72796978A756FB40F6BDD1B1513AA3) [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09131) it's proven that $H_2(\widehat{F}^p, \Bbb F_p)$ is uncountable, where $F$ is a free group of rank at least 2 (more explicitly, this homology group contains $\prod_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb F_p$). Universal coefficient theorem gives that second discrete cohomology with $\Bbb F_p$ coefficients does not vanish as well, and it's well-known fact that for nontrivial projective profinite group (in particular, pro-p completion of a free group) continuous cohomological dimension relative to category of discrete modules is 1.